# JSTree : how can I put form items (like a <select>) into a tree node?

Tags: javascript, jstree

My nodes of [JSTree](http://www.jstree.com/) are of the html type : `"html_titles : true"`.

I would like to put in these nodes items of a form (like `<select>`, `<option>`...).

I can do it with the use of `"rename_node"`, but when the editable item appears, the user can't modify any thing : clicking on the `<select>` item will not let the user modify its content...

It seems that there is a conflict with the drag'n drop plugin : when this plugin is not activated, we can play with form items without any problem... Any ideas about a solution ?

Comment: If I could disable the dnd plugin for a while it would solve my problem. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to disable the drag and drop on a single node, depending on a dynamically attributed class of the node (that I called "inEdition")

But I had to change JSTree code (about line 2400) :

```
.delegate("a", "mousedown.jstree", $.proxy(function (e) { 
    if(e.which === 1) {
        /*this.start_drag(e.currentTarget, e);
        return false;*/
        o = this._get_node(e.currentTarget);
        if(this.data.ui && this.is_selected(o)) { o = this._get_node(null, true); }
        if (!o.hasClass("inEdition")) {
            this.start_drag(e.currentTarget, e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}, this))
```

I also had to disable 3 lines about line 2200 :

```
/*e.currentTarget.unselectable = "on";
e.currentTarget.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
if(e.currentTarget.style) { e.currentTarget.style.MozUserSelect = "none";}*/
```

Hope it may help someone